# Getting “Retrying” paypal IPN Delivery status for some transaction

Tags: php, mysql, paypal-ipn

I am getting 'Retrying' status in the IPN delivery status for few transactions. Most of the transactions are in 'sent' status and I am getting that notifications. But for some transactions I am not able to get notifications which are in 'Retrying' status. Anyone can help me on this...